# There is an extra density in my overlapped ggplot2 density plots

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm using `ggplot2` in R to overlay two density plots. I'm using this command:

```
data$stateOwned  <- data$govtShare > 0
ggplot(subset(data,leverageEq < 3),aes(leverageEq)) + geom_density(aes(fill = stateOwned),alpha=0.4)
```

Note that the fill variable for the density geom is logical, so I can't explain why my plot has three densities, note that the legend only takes on two values:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Edit: Here's the data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x74jsw1n3hfca5d/allMerged.csv

Comment: Please provide a reprodicble example?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be better if you showed us what is in `data`, or better yet post a link to it. Are any of the values in `data$stateOwned` NA?

Comment: Yes there are missing variables on both the data I'm plotting the density for and the filling variable. I'll get a subset of the data to reproduce the error.

Comment: Use `dput(your_data)` and then paste the result in your question.

Comment: What is `leverageCutOff`? It's not in the data frame. And neither is `stateOwned`...

Comment: Sorry, that's just to not plot all the outliers. In the graph above it's three, like I just fixed the command.

Comment: Fixed that too, I'm really sorry, I thought I had saved that to the csv.

Comment: stateOwned doesn't appear in your dataset, so I created a fake stateOwned variable with `data$stateOwned=sample(c("Y","N",NA), nrow(data),replace=TRUE)`. When I did this and then ran your ggplot command, I got the "extra" density plot due to the NA values (as surmised by @jihoward). If you remove them, you'll get the two density plots you expected.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10 , the missing values were it.

Comment: @eipi10 Post that as an answer. Also, small reproducible example if you have one handy.

Comment: As requested, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NA values in the fill variable (`stateOwned`) are causing the "extra" plot to show up. Remove them and you'll get the two plots you were expecting. Here's a small reproducible example:

```
# Data
dat = structure(list(leverageEq = c(0.733, 4.676, 4.676, 1.663, 0.051, 
1.47, 0.092, 0.526, 1.208, 1.663, 0.288, 0.122, 0.36, 0.339, 
0.589, 0.6, 0.212, 0, 0.141, 1.47, 0.28, 0.092, 0.421, 0, 0.098, 
1.098, 0.505, 0.204, 1.253, 0.481), stateOwned = c(NA, NA, "N", 
NA, NA, "Y", NA, NA, NA, "Y", NA, NA, "Y", NA, "Y", NA, NA, "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "N", NA, "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", NA, "N")), .Names = c("leverageEq", 
"stateOwned"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")

# Plot with NA values included (Results in three density plots)
ggplot(dat,aes(leverageEq)) + geom_density(aes(fill=stateOwned),alpha=0.4)

# Plot without NA values included (Results in two density plots)
ggplot(dat[!is.na(dat$stateOwned),],aes(leverageEq)) +
       geom_density(aes(fill=stateOwned),alpha=0.4)
```